# Clojure REPL, interop, Unable to resolve symbol

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

Suppose `files` is a list of Javas `File` in Clojure and I want to obtain a list of file names. In the Leiningen REPL I can use, say,

```
(.getName (nth files 4))
=> "image.jpg"
```

but if I use

```
(map .getName files)
```

the REPL throws a `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: .getName in this context`. Why is that?

I can work around this problem with

```
(defn gn [file] (.getName file))
(map gn files)
```

but I would like to now if there is a more elegant way to map Java methods to lists in Clojure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either use [`memfn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memfn) (which some say you should not use, dont remember why, comments welcome) or simply a lambda:

```
(map (memfn getName) files)   ;;#1
(map #(.getName %) files)     ;;#2
```

as for why, well because these are methods and not functions.

Comment: Did a quick search of the Google group, and here it is, from Rich Hickey himself: [‘memfn preceded #(), the latter now being preferred’](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/Xx-zt7LYzUI/kUQDg1DDNOsJ).

Comment: @glts thank, yes, I also found that exact same statements in the docs, however I was looking more for *why* it is preferred?

Comment: I read it as `memfn` now simply having become an unnecessary convenience. If the `#()` notation had been there from the start, `memfn` would not have been added to core – so it might not be a strong deprecation.

Comment: Nice, thats what I thought. So its not that it's "wrong", it is simply redundant.